# Can we hide (or relocate) the inline tag edit button, please? This is distracting

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, user-interface

It seems that CSS style of Stack Exchange changed again? Now the inline tag edit button for a post consistently shows up, even if you don't hover your mouse over that position. Am I the only one who see this distracting?

Since the inline tag editing is a privilege unlocked at 10k reputation, not all users would observe this. Here is the screenshot for it. I would insert some horizontal rule to separate those pictures otherwise there are so many "Edit" / "edit".

On main site, I see:

### --------------------------------------------

[image]

### --------------------------------------------

On meta site, I see:

[image]

### --------------------------------------------

**Update**

Thanks to Tim Post:

> We do want to make sure 10k users know they have access to it (we're figuring out a lot of people don't learn about privileges as we explore teams). But, we also need to make sure 10k users know it is an inline editor just for tags that won't load the full editor and cause you to navigate to another page, and it needs to be clearly differentiated from 'edit'. They're in the middle of getting all that worked out, sorry about the dust I don't think it was intended for this to show up so early, but we'll get it worked out.

Right now this "Edit" is so prominent that it attracts me (maybe others as well) to click it. Or perhaps, how about relocating tags on the top of the question, right under the title? So the tag edit is on the top and the body edit is on the bottom? Perhaps it would be good as well to include title editing as part of inline editing?

Comment: Hmm.  I remember that not being there as prominently...

Comment: @Makoto On meta site it looks OK, as it has a red colour in contrast to the tag. But on the main site they are all black / gray. I was initially wondering: "What? This question is using a tag: edit"?

Comment: I'm also not a big fan of it being shortened to only "Edit"... Now there's two links on the question that both just say edit...

Comment: @李哲源 I take less umbrage to the color scheme and more to its permanent existence, honestly.

Comment: It is quite distracting and confusing, yes.

Comment: Can you add an image? I'm not sure what you're referring to by "inline tag edit button"

Comment: @osdavison It's a 10k priv. See the last section here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Note that if the request times out (upon clicking), the loading animation does ... interesting things. I'm almost positive this wasn't intentional. We're looking at it.

Comment: The _At least one tag is required._ message now always shows too, afaik that used to only show if you removed all tags.

Comment: This used to be hidden until you hovered the tags.

Comment: This topic on Meta.SE: [No more hovering to edit tags above 10k!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315371/289905).

Comment: For those who have installed my [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js), I have just pushed a change to display the Edit link only on mouseover.

Comment: ^ "reducing clutter" being the entire reason it was made that way to begin with. I guess the designers revisited that design decision recently.

Comment: Okay, update: We do want to make sure 10k users know they have access to it (we're figuring out a lot of people don't learn about privileges as we explore teams). But, we also need to make sure 10k users know _it is an inline editor just for tags_ that won't load the full editor and cause you to navigate to another page, and it needs to be clearly differentiated from 'edit'. They're in the middle of getting all that worked out, sorry about the dust I don't think it was intended for this to show up so early, but we'll get it worked out.

Comment: @TimPost if it's going to remain, [can the design be made more consistent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374061/inline-tag-edit-design-inconsistency)

Comment: @Tanner I stressed that as a major point of confusion surrounding how this change appeared. The eventual goal is to reduce clutter _and_ make sure folks know what features they can use (I know that sounds lofty!) Designers are meeting now to work out how to advertise the feature _and_ its nuances while also staying consistent with everything else.

Comment: @TimPost thanks, also, I don't think my question is a dupe of this, as I'm asking for design update, not to hide it again. Should I bother trying to reopen or can I assume that it's in hand?

Comment: Also, folks, just tossing this out there: we're getting older (as a company); there's but a _handful_ of us that remember particular sets of circumstances when certain things were implemented. I'm really warmed that folks are being so helpful and patient despite probably wondering if it was just careless (it wasn't, some of our stuff is just complicated). Thank you all for that. The product teams will make sure we at least get a post out if we change something that unlocks with rep, even if it seems like a small thing. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @Tanner I reopened your post and left a comment, I think it still stands pending however we end up styling the link to make it more clear what it actually does (along with what it's for).

Comment: @TimPost It's definitely confusing. Already three times, today, I clicked the wrong `edit` link. At least caption it "edit tags", please?

Comment: The great thing about this new feature is that it only inflicts power users. None of the usual excuses for trying to help new users apply.

Comment: @TimPost Re: your initial comment - it was already made aware to us upon earning it... and it was also more clear (it said "edit tags"). This change added confusion in duplicate-looking links and also removed valuable information that your comment claims was the impetus for the change... Did this change go through any sort of change control? That would be very useful for preventing future erroneous changes to the CSS of the site like we have seen a ton of in the past several weeks and months... to be candid.

Comment: @TylerH: Also has strong "change for the sake of change" vibes to me

Answer (score 9):

Adding here because I think it deserves an answer:  Samuel Liew's script changes it to only appear on mouse-over event, like this:

[image]

I installed it with tampermonkey in approximately 2 seconds by visiting this link, and it worked perfectly

https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ReduceClutter.user.js

And, you can too! Thanks to Samuel, whining on meta about this trivial design change is entirely optional.

Comment: Can you update your animation to reflect the new name?

Answer (score 4):

I might be alone here, but the hiding was distracting sometimes for me.
Some questions which use 5 really long tags made the tags relocate when you hovered over them just to show the edit button, and that was pretty annoying.

Overall, I find this as a good change.

---

Maybe this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I read "edit tags" rather than "edit":

[image]

Comment: I disapprove the "_Overall, I find this as a good change._" for when it was named "Edit" only: clearly it was confusing to have 2 different actions with the same label. I approve the [tag:status-completed] remark of your post regarding the renaming to "Edit tags".

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your feedback. As we made some changes to the inline tag editor for Stack Overflow for Teams, we thought that showing this edit button globally on network sites would also be beneficial to those users who have unlocked this privilege.

We've updated the copy from "Edit" to "Edit tags" on public sites since it was being confused for the edit post button. Although the capitalization and color of the "Edit tags" button is inconsistent with some other links on the page, we've decided not to change it for the following reasons:

1. Capitalizing the first letter follows our copy guideline of sentence casing. In cases where we haven’t followed this in the past, we update them as we come across them.
2. Links match site themes, which is also a best practice for us.

You brought up some interesting ideas about relocating the tags under the title and making the title editable inline. I'll be relaying this to the team.

Thanks again for your report.

Comment: Matching the themes is good but some themes links are in bold which is not a good match in this case. See the Japanese Language site, for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgia7.png The color is one thing, the weighting probably not necessary here.

Comment: @Catija thanks for catching that. Going to push a fix for the weighting.