# Tags input placeholder text cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, google-chrome, firefox

Notice how the input's placeholder text has been cut off.

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Chrome (69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit))

[image]

Comment: Likely related to [Can we hide the inline tag edit button, please? This is distracting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374024/7296893), which is an unintentional change as far as I understand, and will probably be reverted.

Comment: Also reproduces in Firefox. It's caused by the `width: 19px;` on the input element.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [“Type a tag” text cut off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315383/289905).

Comment: For the question in the comment, you may want to enter more text than the OS and Browser versions... like a textual description of the bug in more detail. You have essentially the same exact text content with a different image, that's why it thinks it's a duplicate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ah, yes. You are correct. I have posted a new question regarding it. I thought they would take in to account the question's tags too. Cleaning up previous comment.

Comment: Also reproduces on MacOS in Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.16 (Official Build) beta (64-bit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams.