# Tags misaligned on ask question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, user-interface

I'm running Firefox 62.0 on Windows 10.

The tags in the tag box don't appear to be aligned with the middle of the box on the ask question page.

[image: screenshot].

Comment: Ah, I’ve been waiting for this report here! Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Vertical alignment of tags differs between Ask page and inline tag editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315373/289905).

Comment: Found another bug  [Type getting  cut with e missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7DIg.png)

Comment: @BlackMamba That’s [Tags input placeholder text cut off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374060/4642212) on Meta.SO and [“Type a tag” text cut off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315383/289905) on Meta.SE.

Comment: Basically, the tags box is currently FUBARd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor (a multi-line, wrapping tag editor) snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams