# Bug in tag chooser on ask question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

I've noticed that there is a set of bugs in the ask question page, specifically the tag choosing input:

[With no tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PksrI.png)

[With tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxzJM.png)

[With one tag deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebeBi.png)

I know there is a question about [misaligned tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374087/tags-misaligned-on-ask-question-page), but this shows more issues that would possibly make users confused.

Comment: The last one is just some space reserved for writing a new tag name in that space. It goes away if you click outside.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more aesthetic to have a single space (` `) for that purpose?

Comment: The first issue is a dupe of [Tags input placeholder text cut off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374060/4642212).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just though centralising all these related issues would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor (a multi-line, wrapping tag editor) snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams

The last screenshot is, as noted in comments, triggered by the presence of a cursor before the first (remaining) tag - if the cursor is re-positioned, the then-unnecessary space disappears.