# Placeholder text for tags is cut off on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, asking-questions, meta

As you can see the placeholder text is cut off. This is only happening on Meta Stack Overflow.

[image: Editor]

Comment: I see this also on MacOS Safari (latest).

Comment: @window.document: That edit box looks wider than 19px.

Comment: Removing the `style="width: 19px;"` part fixed it for me. But I don't know enough about web development to understand the reason for the styling and the consequences of removing it.

Comment: That is actually the fix to the bug. @CrisLuengo

Comment: It’s this bug _again_: [Tags input placeholder text cut off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374060/4642212).

Comment: The `style="width: 19px";` is being dynamically added by a piece of JavaScript. While you can remove it, it reappears when trying to add a tag, and the bug is probably in that piece of JS as well.

Comment: Can reproduce on Firefox 67.0 (latest), running on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Also reproducable on [meta.se], [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com), and other main and meta sites with longish tag suggestions (i.e. [codegolf.se])

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Ask question - Tags - partial placeholder text truncated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329175/289905).

Comment: The CSS rule: .`tag-editor input[type="text"]:not([placeholder=""])` should have its  `min-width` set to `400px` instead of the `237px` it currently has. The minimum design width seems to be 500px and if I resize where the leftbar comes into full view again 400px still works and doesn't seem to cause negative side-effects in Chrome. Not verified on other browsers.