# Inline tag edit design inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

I couldn't find details of when this was implemented, but it seems like [this old request was implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336522/edit-tags-button-should-be-always-visible-for-privileged-users), although it's not marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

The design for always having the inline edit link visible for users that can edit, seems inconsistent with the other post action links:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When I first saw it, it looked closer in design to a tag than an edit link.

I think that if it's going to be visible, it should have the same design as the other action links below it and it should say "edit tags" like it used to, which makes it clearer.

Looking at the [moderator tools guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), it shows what it used to look like, when you had to hover over it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

That moderator tools page also needs updating if this is to remain a non-hover/always visible option.

**UPDATE**

As per [@shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374211/57475), this has now been partially actioned, but I still think the styling and casing should be inline with the other action links. Also, the [moderator tools guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) requires updating (low hanging fruit).

Comment: Marking as a duplicate because there's work to be done. [The change might be unintentional](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7228544#7228544), so nothing else should be updated.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks, i didn't see that post. Could be a dupe but I'm asking for a design change if it is to remain vs that post asking to hide it again.

Comment: Re-opened this because it's about the _design_ of the link, not so much that it's not hidden. As the change is only half-baked at this point (sorry about that!!!) we _do_ need to make sure that link at least somehow _hints_ that it's not going to load the full editor, along with differentiating it from just 'edit' in naming. This still stands in that context, so should stay open.

Comment: @Tim Post: Was there significant user feedback that led the designers to conclude that the existing design was no longer meeting that goal? Or was this change instituted simply because none of the new designers could figure out why the original design was there and this uncertainty was bothering them so much?

Comment: @BoltClock We can see how often stuff gets clicked, and there are some features that just don't get discovered like they used to (presumably, because everyone that _knew_ they'd unlock the inline tag editor at 10k and thus looked for it have already found it (or aren't contributing any longer)). We're also gonna have to reconcile that /tools doesn't scale well, along with tag synonyms never seeing much light or voting (and stuff like that).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now reads: "Edit tags". Yes, still with the annoying capitalization and coloring, but without the wording ambiguity!

[image: screenshot of edit tags link]

Comment: I'd say this is partially complete rather than [status-complete]...

Comment: I'm told the rest of it is firmly by-design, so... This is probably as completed as it's gonna get (also expect all the other links to change to match at some undetermined point in the future). I've updated the help center to match.

Comment: @Shog9 ugh. i liked it when it was a more subtle color.

Answer (score 6):

I agree wholeheartedly with this. Its more visible/recognizable to me than the tags themselves. Also I could go in to debating `Edit` vs `edit`.