# Inline tag editing broken for teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

It appears that the inline editor for tags on [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is broken.

When clicking on the edit link, the following error is displayed:

[image]

Checking my browser's developer panel, a request is made to

`https://stackoverflow.com/c/[team_name]/posts/63/edit-tags?isMultiLine=true&numColumns=1&_=[redacted]`

The server responds with a 404 to this request. Editing tags via the regular edit form works fine.

Comment: possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374061/inline-tag-edit-design-inconsistency

Comment: You still seeing this? I can't reproduce.

Comment: @Shog9 I just tried, and I can still reproduce this on Chrome. Additionally to that, it seems that the update to rename "Edit" to "Edit tags" wasn't applied to teams either, but I guess it's less impoortant there because the tags and the edit link are aligned in a different manner.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to reproduce this. Stand by...

Comment: A'ight. The change to show this for everyone overrides the privilege check in one place (the question renderer) but not the others (the editor itself, or the route that applies the edits). So you can see the edit link, but can't load the editor and couldn't *submit* the editor even if you could see it. And of course, this check is overridden for admins and developers, so no one noticed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! This should be fixed with our next production build.